# I have a bunch of cvs .~ files. Can I delete them?

Tags: cvs

I have a bunch of files with the exentension similar to .~1.23.~
These are obviously created by CVS at some point.

Does anyone know why CVS created them, and is it safe to delete them?

Can I make CVS itself delete them (sounds like a better option).

Agnar

Comment: The better option would be to use a less awful version control solution.

Answer (score 2):

The files were more likely created by your editor [when said editor noticed that you were using CVS](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/emacs/emacs_150.html):

> The name of the automatic version backup for version *version* of file *file* is *file.~version.~*

You can delete them. You won't find a CVS command related to them since CVS did not create them but only provided the version number used to name them.